# getting error file cannot blank in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

though uploading file in yii2, but still getting validation that Profile Pic cannot be blank. my code is as follows of rule. please help me how to overcome this problem.

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['profile_pic'], 'file'],
        [ ['profile_pic'], 'required', 'on' => 'update_pic']];
}
```

from controller

```
$model = new PostForm(['scenario' => 'update_pic']);
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '') && $model->validate()) {
    return ['status' => 1, 'message' => Yii::$app->params['messages']['post_success']];
} else {
    $model->validate();
    return $model;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: added code from calling this rule

Comment: Read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html because you are not processing the uploaded file properly.

Comment: i am not looking for response return in model as per above code

Comment: let me know if any thing missing in above code

Comment: @bhavika UploadedFile instance is missing. It is mentioned in the linked guide and you need to use it no matter if you are "looking for response return" or not.

Comment: Please follow @Bizley's suggestion and read that document properly. Using `$model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->getBodyParams(), '')` does not assign the uploaded file to the model. File input needs to be handled separately using `UploadedFile::getInstance()` in the controller. So I repeat again, please go through the link @Bizley posted - especially the section titled [**Wiring Up**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#wiring-up)

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Bizley and @sm1979 have commented, you are not handling the file upload as it needs to be done.

The actual file is not received the same way as other post params, reason why you need to use `UploadedFile::getInstance` to get the instance of the file and assign it to the`profile_pic` attribute in your model.

In your Controller:

```
$model = new PostForm(['scenario' => 'update_pic']);
// We load the post params from the current request
if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    // We assign the file instance to profile_pic in your model.
    // We need to do this because the uploaded file is not a part of the
    // post params.
    $model->profile_pic = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'profile_pic')
    // We call a new upload method from your model. This method calls the
    // model's validate method and saves the uploaded file.
    // This is important because otherwise the uploaded file will be lost
    // as it is a temporary file and will be deleted later on.
    if($model->upload()) {
        return ['status' => 1, 'message' => Yii::$app->params['messages']['post_success']];
    }
}
return $model;
```

In your Model:

```
public function upload() {
    // We validate the model before doing anything else
    if($this->validate()) {
        // The model was validated so we can now save the uploaded file.
        // Note how we can get the baseName and extension from the 
        // uploaded file, so we can keep the same name and extension.
        $this->profile_pic->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->profile_pic->baseName . '.' . $this->profile_pic->extension);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Finally, just a recommendation: read the [The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html). Reading this and the [Yii2 API Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/) is the best way to learn Yii2 by yourself.